# View XML Path including attributes in Notepad++ or Sublime

Tags: xml, notepad++, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm editing some large xml files that are deeply nested and I'm paranoid that I'm going to make a change to the wrong section.

The name of the tags and their structure is similar for each of the branches, the only way to know where you are is by looking at id or name attributes. (This means tools like "XML Tools" for Notepad++ are not helpful when displaying the "Current XML Path" because they exclude the attributes which are required in this case)

Is there a plugin for Notepad++ or Sublimetext that can quickly show this.

For example, if I was in an a branch of the XML, it would be good to see something like this in the status bar maybe or as a pop up:

`Location/Path: root > child1 (attr1: x1, attr2: y1) > gchild1 (gc2attr1: x2)`

That would be for a structure like this:

`<root>
    <child1 attr1="x1" attr2="y1">
        <gchild1 gc2attr1="x2">
        <!-- Cursor here-->
        </gchild1>
    </child1>
</root>`

Comment: Are you also open to option to try (free) tools different from editors your mentioned?

Comment: Sure, not ideally because I know my way around these two, but always open to options!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plugin for Sublime Text 3, available on Package Control, called [xpath](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/xpath) which will display the  XPath in the status bar that relates to the current cursor position.

You can edit the user preferences for the package so that it shows the attributes you want (either specific attributes, or all attributes).

Disclaimer: I am a developer that has contributed to this plugin's development.

Comment: Thanks Keith, that looks like it will do exactly what I want. How do I change the user preference, is it just done through the standard preferences.sublime-settings file? Do I just include this line: `"show_all_attributes": true`

Comment: You need to edit the user specific settings file for this plugin, not the standard preferences.sublime-settings file. The plugin should have created a new menu entry: Preferences -> Package Settings -> XPath -> Settings - User, which will open the file you need. Initially, it will be blank. You will want to write `{ "show_all_attributes": true }` and save the file. The plugin will then automatically reload the settings and display the xpath you want :)

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on your main goal – avoiding mistakes during XML edit:

perhaps you can try free [XML Notepad 2007 from the Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7973) ([current version on github](https://github.com/microsoft/xmlnotepad)). It is a bit old, but it allows editing parts of XML tree directly and has other XML essentials like reordering XML nodes or validation. It can also search according to XPath. It also has seamless navigation between XML tree and content (using <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> keys).

[image]

Maybe not exactly you want, but I was thinking about helping you. If you like this path of thinking, you can learn about other similar tools at [Software Recommendations StackExchange site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or at [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/).

Regarding Notepad++, I think I know offer of its plugins but I'm not aware of interactive breadcrumb functionality, showing you current XML path, in any plugin.